# Removing a block of text lines

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

Scenario:

```
#Start1
text
text
text
#Start2
text
#Start3
text
text
```

As shown above, the blocks are not certain with the number of lines contained with it. Question is how to utilize `unix` command to remove one of the block say `#Start2`.

I tried

```
less <file_name> | sed '/Start2/.+1d' | less
```

yes it probably works for this case if I can be sure how many lines are tailing the `#Start2`

But what if the number of lines tailing it is not constant each and everytime `#Start2` happens? I might fail to remove all of it or accidentally remove some content of other block.

I need a more sophisticated way of knowing it hits the end of the block. Is there any?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '/^#/ {f=0} /^#Start2/ {f=1} !f;' file
#Start1
text
text
text
#Start3
text
text
```

This `awk` prints all line as long as `f=0` or not true.
`f` starts with default `empty` same as `0`
If line starts with `#` set `f` to `0`, so print line.
If line starts with `#Start2` set `f` to `1`, do not print.
This will make `awk` prints all line and stop if it finds `#Start2`, then continue again if it finds `#`

---

Another way to do it:

```
awk '!/Start2/' RS=# ORS=# file
#Start1
text
text
text
#Start3
text
text
```

This tell that a record starts with `#`
If record contains `Start2`, then do not print it. All other would be printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
PatStart="#Start2"
PatBlockEnd="^#"
sed -n "/${PatStart}/,/${PatBlockEnd}/ {
   /${PatStart}/ {x;s/.*//;x;}
   x;p;}" YourFile
```

Use the 2 Pat... var for setting your block border (End assume this is a new block starting on a NEW LINE, not the end of current block in this case).